# Mosaico - can emailed templates be copied to appear in Mosaico template option

Tags: mosaico, message-templates

Users have created some Mosaico based emails but have created and saved them only within an email, and have not used the 'Mosaico Templates' option.  Some are newsletters that it would be useful to just update rather than redevelop. Is it possible to now copy those developed templates from the emails so they appear in the 'Mosaico Templates' option?  This would make them more easily reusable.  Using 5.67.3 with Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of the Mailing and re-use the mosaic template

Comment: I'm aware of that but also planning to delete all mailings due to an separate issue.  Therefore I'd like to liberate the Mosaico templates from mailings & have them in the Mosaico Templates option.

Comment: That's a useful workaround but does not address the question of turning a mailing into a template.